# get specific key and value from Web Scraping by using XML

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping

How can code to find out fips when month is 2019, month is August and locality is King and Queen?

[image]

I started with import requests

```py
from lxml import objectify


URL = 'https://data.virginia.gov/api/views/xvir-sctz/rows.xml?accessType=DOWNLOAD'

response = requests.get(URL).content

import requests
from lxml import objectify

#parsing the XML file
root = objectify.fromstring(response)

#take a look at the data
print(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will probably use `panda` dataframe for this as it is simpler to deal with the data and filtering:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_xml('https://data.virginia.gov/api/views/xvir-sctz/rows.xml?accessType=DOWNLOAD', xpath='row//row')[['year','month','fips','locality']]
df.columns = ['Year','Month','Fips','Locality']
print(df)

fips_df = df.query('Year == 2019.0 & Month == "August" & Locality.str.contains("King and Queen")')
print(fips_df)
```

Output like this:

[image]

You can change the query to suite your needs:

```
fips_df = df.query('Year == 2019.0 & Month == "August" & Locality.str.contains("King and Queen")')
```

Comment: You actually can run that entire logic in the `xpath` query: `'.//row[Year=2019 and Month='August' and contains(Locality, 'King and Queen')]'`.